# Using MASM32 with Win32, how can I add the path & file name to the title of a dialog box & then remove the added info when the file is closed?

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86, masm32

I'm using the Win32 lstrcat instruction to concatenate my dialog box title (i.e., AppName) with the path & file name of a file that is opened in the dialog box (i.e., ofn.lpstrFile) and then using the Win32 SetWindowText instruction to change the title of the dialog box to the concatented version of Appname.  The problem I am encountering is that I am unable to remove the path & file name from the dialog box title when I close the file.  In addition, the title and text of other messageboxes are unexpectedly being changed and I don't understand why.

When I close the file, I've tried copying over the conactenated version of AppName with a duplicate of the original AppName that I saved before the performing the concatenation but that seems to eliminate the original title and part of the path name leaving a portion of the path & file name in the dialog box title.  I also tried referencing a different variable name for the titles of other message boxes but they still display the concatenated strings.

The followng code is the most recent version of the procedure I tried.

```
ChangeDialogBoxTitle PROC hWnd

; Copy Current Title

push esi
push edi
invoke lstrlen,addr AppName
mov ecx,eax
LEA esi, AppName
LEA edi, AppNameDUP
push ds
pop es
cld
rep movsb [edi],[esi]
pop edi
pop esi

; CLEAR Current Title

push esi
push edi
invoke lstrlen,addr AppName
mov ecx,eax
LEA esi, BLANK
LEA edi, AppName
push ds
pop es
cld
rep movsb [edi],[esi]
pop edi
pop esi
                
; Replace AppName with AppNameDUP

push esi
push edi
invoke lstrlen,addr AppName
mov ecx,eax
LEA esi, AppNameDUP
LEA edi, AppName
push ds
pop es
cld
rep movsb [edi],[esi]
pop edi
pop esi
                
; Add file info

.IF ActiveFileFlag==1
    invoke lstrcat,addr AppName,ofn.lpstrFile
    invoke SetWindowText,hWnd,AppName
.ENDIF
invoke SetFocus,hTextInput
    Ret
ChangeDialogBoxTitle endp
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to resolving this issue is to ensure that the buffer for the concatenated strings is large enough to hold both strings.  So I defined a new variable named AppNameBuffer and defined it in the .data segment of the program as:

```
    AppNameBuffer db 512 DUP (" "),0
```

With that addition, the following code worked fine:

```
;******************************************************************************
; DISPLAY File Path/Name in Dialog Box Title Bar
;******************************************************************************
; BEFORE adding the PATH & FILENAME, copy ORIGINAL AppName 
; into AppNameBuffer from the DUPLICATE COPY in AppNameDUP
            invoke lstrcpy,addr AppNameBuffer,addr AppNameDUP
; Concatenate file path & name string of opened file to application name
; string
            invoke lstrcat, addr AppNameBuffer, ofnSA.lpstrFile 
; Set the text in the Dialog Box Title Bar to the concatentated version of 
; AppNameBuffer
        invoke SetWindowText,hDlg,addr AppNameBuffer
;******************************************************************************
```